# A Jumping Frog and Powers of Two

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

I recently solved this question:

Consider $n(>1)$ lotus leaves placed around a circle. A frog jumps from one leaf to another in the following manner. It starts from some selected leaf. From there, it skips one leaf in the clockwise direction and jumps to the next one. Then it skips exactly two leaves in the clockwise direction and jumps to the next one. Then the frog skips three leaves in the clockwise direction and so on. Suppose it turns out that the frog continues this way and all the leaves are visited by the frog. Show that $n$ cannot be odd.

Now, I want to prove that the frog may visit all leaves if and only if the number of leaves is some power of two. I've seen discussions regarding this on this site, but I don't quite understand them. A hint to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: If reading this right, after $j=0,1,2,3,\ldots$ hops, the frog has travelled clockwise by $d_j=0,2,5,9,14,\ldots$ leaves, or $d_j=(j+1)(j+2)/2-1$.  Is that correct?

Comment: Well, I numbered the leaves from 0 to n-1. After the ith jump, the frog would be on the leaf numbered [i(i+3)/2] (mod n). I'm not sure what numbering you used.

Comment: Your two expressions for the position after a number of jumps agree.  The $-1$ in the mjqxxxx formula takes care of the constant term from (j+1)(j+2).

Comment: Right, the same.  And after $j$ hops the frog is about to move by $j+2$ (mod $n$).  So after $n$ hops we’ve moved to leaf $n(n+3)/2$ (mod $n$) and are back where we started with hop lengths.  If we hit all the leaves already, or if we missed some leaves but have shifted by a distance relatively prime with $n$, we’re good.  Otherwise we will never hit all the leaves.  Still seems right?

Comment: @mjqxxxx yeah it seems right to me

Comment: Note that if $n$ is odd, then $n(n+3)/2 \equiv 0 \bmod n$, so you are back to where you started after $n$ hops, and will just repeat the same pattern from then on. Also consider that $k + (k+1) = 2k+1$